# A better way to query for 'any number' with Active Record in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a a Model with integer date field format like this: 20131211. What would be the appropriate Activerecord query to select all of the objects that have exact same numbers **apart from the ones I'd like to replace**? So in my case its 201312NN or in someone else's it could be 1234NN78.

I could go with something like

```
scope :show_query, lambda { where('startdate <= and enddate >= ?', 20131201, 20131231) }
```

but isn't there a better way?

Comment: Do you have one or two date field in your table ?

Comment: yes i have a date field, and I could query by month, but I'm using integer for performance reasons

Comment: I suspect that using timestamp will work as fast as integers, and you will have to write less code. For example, you need validations for not allowing store 30th February, and since performance is an issue for you, you can't use date commands on SQL like `add_date`.

Comment: @fotanus my validations are still in place, however when saving an object, I duplicate its "transaction_date" as an integer and index on it to speed the performance up. So no februaries 31st.

Comment: It's a common anti-pattern in relational databases to store dates in non-Date datatypes -- performance is the usual quoted reason, but it does not hold up to scrutiny. For example you obscure patterns from the RDBMS query optimiser -- how many unique days are there in the range 20121218 to 20130302 inclusive? The numeric range is 9085, but the date range is 75 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you date is really a integer just divide by 100

```
scope : show_query, lambda { where ('date DIV 100 = ?', 201312) }
```

Alternatively you can use like :

```
where('date like ?', '201312__')
```

But that's slower.
With MySQL you don't need to convert the date to a String, I'm not sure if it's standard SQL or not.

Comment: that does not answer my question though, what if I would like query something like 8474910374NNNN45

Comment: That's another question, Your question is (in bold) "apart from the last two"

Comment: that would be `like '8474910374_____45'`, see my update update

Comment: that is much clearer! How do I use this syntax with params? Like if scope :show_by_month, lambda { |d| where('dateinteger = ?', d) }

Comment: Just use ? as in my answer